# Load Scala file into interpreter to use functions?

Tags: scala, interpreter

I have some Scala functions defined in a file, not in a class, and I would like to use them in the Scala interpreter. I know I can say `scala filename.scala` to simply run the file and exit the interpreter, but I would like to run the file and then stay in the interpreter so I can do some testing. Can anyone tell me how to simply load a file into the interpreter so I can use the functions defined within it?

Comment: `:load /path/to/file` in scala REPL

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Don't know why it was so hard to find.

Comment: Jamil, please, post this as an answer, so that Bea Metitiri could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

type `:load /path/to/file` in Scala REPL.

You can get complete list of available commands by typing `:help`

Comment: This seems to evaluate it one definition at a time, which doesn't work if the file has a sealed trait or forward references. `:paste /path/to/file` works better, as mentioned in Suresh's answer.

Answer (score 25):

On occasions, `:paste` might be your better friend (than `:load`). Here is an example on how to use *:paste*.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

if (true)
  print("that was true")
else
  print("false")

[Ctrl-D]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

that was true
```

One can also use `:paste` to load a file using following command `:paste [path]`

```
scala> :paste ~/Desktop/repl_seeder.scala
Pasting file ~/Desktop/repl_seeder.scala...
defined object test1

scala> test1.main(Str)
my first scala program
```

Answer (score 5):

Just reminder, put the complete path. I found problem in Linux by doing like this:

> :load ~/fileName.scala

to get rid of error "That file does not exist" I did

> :load /complete/path/fileName.scala

Comment: That's only a problem because Scala doesn't know how to expand `~` to your home directory.

Comment: relative paths are supported, too. So if you do `:load foo/bar/baz.scala`, it works, at least of today.