# How to load a scala file in the sbt console?

Tags: scala, sbt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load Scala file into interpreter to use functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383436/load-scala-file-into-interpreter-to-use-functions)

I start the sbt console like this:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/projects$ sbt console
[info] Set current project to default-8aceda (in build file:/home/alex/projects/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK Client VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

I have a `test.scala` (/home/alex/projects/test.scala) file with something like this:

```
def timesTwo(i: Int): Int = {
  println("hello world")
  i * 2
}
```

How to do it so that I can do something like this in the console:

```
scala> timesTwo
```

And output the value of the function?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. `sbt console` compiles the source file on start-up, so you only have to `Times timesTwo 7`. (I had wrapped it in a Times object like Brian. Coincidence or fate?)

Comment: Agreed. This is not a duplicate. sbt and scala consoles behave differently in this respect.

Answer (score 17):

In short, use the `:load` function in the scala REPL to load a file. Then you can call that function in the file if you wrap it in an object or class since `sbt` tries to compile it. Not sure if you can do it with just a function definition.

Wrap it in an `object` to get `sbt` to compile it correctly.

```
object Times{
  def timesTwo(i: Int): Int = {
    println("hello world")
    i * 2
  }
}
```

Load the file:

```
 scala> :load Times.scala
 Loading Times.scala...
 defined module Times
```

Then call `timesTwo` in `Times`:

```
 scala> Times.timesTwo(2)
 hello world
 res0: Int = 4
```

If you want just the function definition without wrapping it in a `class` or `object` the you can paste it with the command `:paste` in the scala REPL/sbt console.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def timesTwo(i: Int): Int = {
  println("hello world")
  i * 2
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

timesTwo: (i: Int)Int
```

This can be called by just the function name.

```
 scala> timesTwo(2)
 hello world
 res1: Int = 4
```

Comment: How does it know where to load it from, what is the default directory

Comment: @Mike The directory you ran `scala` in.

Comment: how do you specify the directory?  I can't give it a path

Comment: @Mike Something like `:load /path/to/file.txt` should work.

Comment: ` import com._` illegal start of definition, does it not auto import dependencies?