# chained method call not parsing correctly in sbt console only

Tags: scala, console, sbt

I write a **scala script** string_split.sc:

```
val s = "  some  interesting stuff ...   "

// this does not work
val x = s.toLowerCase()
    .replaceAll("[^\\w']", " ")
    .split(" ")
    .filter(w => w.trim.length >=1)
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.size)
```

when load it in sbt console with :load:

```
scala> :load src/main/scala/string_split.sc

src/main/scala/string_split.sc:1: error: illegal start of definition
.replaceAll("[^\\w']", " ")
^
src/main/scala/string_split.sc:1: error: illegal start of definition
.split(" ")
^
src/main/scala/string_split.sc:1: error: illegal start of definition
.filter(w => w.trim.length >=1)
^
src/main/scala/string_split.sc:1: error: illegal start of definition
.groupBy(identity)
^
src/main/scala/string_split.sc:1: error: illegal start of definition
.mapValues(_.size)
```

sbt console can not parsing the line start with '.'

The code is fine to load in scala REPL directly.
compile it also fine.
':paste' it to sbt console also fine.

Only the sbt console has problem to load this.
Is it a bug in sbt console?
Is there work around?

my **build.sbt** is simple:

```
name := "Simple SBT"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898373/how-to-load-a-scala-file-in-the-sbt-console Wrap everything in an `object` and then load it. Which version of  `SBT` you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a scala file in the sbt console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898373/how-to-load-a-scala-file-in-the-sbt-console)

Comment: The question is not about how to load scala file. Only sbt console show syntax error when :load the script file. It is fine if compile it . BTW, I write this code snipet as scala script with .sc and file extention

Comment: Your question is a subset of that question, or maybe just slightly different. If you read the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898373/how-to-load-a-scala-file-in-the-sbt-console carefully you'll find the answer to your question as well.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari, Thank you for your patient to explain to me. It do works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scala (SBT) Console parses statements line by line. Therefore, when it parses the line `val x = s.toLowerCase()`, it detects it as a complete statement and assigns the value of `s.toLowerCase` to `val x`.

Therefore, when it proceeds to the next line, the statement starts with a dot, making it an illegal statement. This happens for all the statements that start with a dot. To rectify this, change your statement to end with a dot symbol instead as follows:

```
val x = s.toLowerCase.
          replaceAll("[^\\w']", " ").
          split(" ").
          filter(w => w.trim.length >=1).
          groupBy(identity).
          mapValues(_.size)
```

This will work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Scala REPL, or scala console also works with the '.' at the beginning of line. Only SBT console does not work. Just wonder what special about SBT console.

Comment: and, it works in SBT console if use ':paste' as well. Only ':load' in SBT console does not work.